# MySql error : Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the error : `Result consisted of more than one row but i can't find out it.`

The entry id_user has only one record in its table.

The procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_user_deep`(id_user int(11))
BEGIN

declare nome_loc varchar(45);
declare cognome_loc varchar(45);

select nome,cognome
into nome_loc,cognome_loc
from user
where id_user=id_user;

delete from Radius.radcheck where username in (
    select mac_address from machine where id_user =id_user);

delete from Radius.radreply where username in (
    select mac_address from machine where id_user =id_user);

delete from machine_ip where id_machine in (
    select id_machine from machine where id_user=id_user);

delete from machine where id_user = id_user;

delete from document where id_user=id_user;

delete from user where id_user=id_user;

insert into log_generic values(
                    NULL,
                    'USER',
                    'Delete User Deep',
                    (select concat ('User: ',id_user,' Name: ',cognome_loc,' Prename: ',nome_loc)),
                    now());

END
```

Comment: This is MySQL code so I'm removing the sql-server tag.

Comment: Check `select concat ('User: ',id_user,' Name: ',cognome_loc,' Prename: ',nome_loc)`

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement:

```
select nome,cognome
into nome_loc,cognome_loc
from user
where id_user=id_user;
```

This will return an error if there is more than one row.  The error is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).

This is caused because the parameter name is the same as the column name.  The `id_user` is referring to the column on both sides of the comparison.

The query should look like:

```
select nome, cognome
into nome_loc, cognome_loc
from user
where id_user = param_id_user;
```

*Always* prefix parameter and variable names with something to distinguish them from column names.

Comment: Yes Gordon, i checked it and i found that problem, i replaced id_user as id_user_in and it works! thank you very much